# DataFrame Split Column by Enter key

Tags: python, pandas

I am transforming a dataframe from Excel that has data that is split by 'enter' within the same cell

Example below (reminder that this is one data point):

```
Company Name
6221 - Jacksonville, FL
Total Stock
This is a description
$400
$999
```

Expected output:

```
Company | Location | Stock | Description | Price | High
Company Name | Jacksonville FL | Total Stock | This is a Description | $400 | $999
```

How would I use pandas to parse each of these lines into unique columns?

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: Expected output added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = '''Company Name
6221 - Jacksonville, FL
Total Stock
This is a description
$400
$999'''
d = {'raw_col': [raw_data]}
raw_df = pd.DataFrame(d)

col_names = ['Company', 'Location', 'Stock', 'Description', 'Price', 'High']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)

for index, row in raw_df.iterrows():
    col_items = row['raw_col'].split('\n')
    col_items[1] = col_items[1].split(' - ')[-1]
    new_row = {name: item for name, item in zip(col_names, col_items)}
    df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
        Company          Location        Stock            Description Price  High
0  Company Name  Jacksonville, FL  Total Stock  This is a description  $400  $999
```